# Get value by key from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, key

I'm experiencing an issue with getting the value from a javascript array.

```
var color = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < datafeatures.length - 1; i++) {
    color[datafeatures[i].properties.userid] = datafeatures[i].properties.linecolor;
}

snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
     var colour = childSnapshot.wp_user;
     console.log(color[colour]);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(color));
     console.log(color);
     console.log(colour);
}
```

Console.log result:

**color[colour]:** undefined

**JSON.stringify(color):** []

**color:**

```
[]
 26: "#9d36ee"
 45: "#b1c743"
 56: "#f9c53c"
 61: "#d770ce"
 63: "#267fa1"
 64: "#85002f"
 68: "#78eca8"
 92: "#a4a2e7"
length: 93
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**colour:** 61

Expected output from color[colour]: "#d770ce"

Real output from color[colour]: undefined.

Color has something in it, Colour is a number (key), but it seems impossible to get a value from Color..

Comment: Most likely there are issues with your colour, we can not test your code is we can not test problematic areas. Please create test environment or create fake arrays to see how it works.

Comment: You are traversing `snapshot`, is that the correct variable ?

Comment: For consistency and code clarity (and also by convention), you should name your array (or object) `colours` and one of its elements `colour`. Naming the array `color` and one of its element `colour` is just confusing.

Comment: @jkris Yes, `console.log(JSON.strinify(color));` returns `[]` and as you pointed out in your answer below, when changing the color array to an object, it returns `{}`

Comment: do a console log before forEach `console.log(color)`

Comment: @Fawaz There's no difference with `console.log(color)` inside the forEach

Comment: @jkris It's just javascript inside a .php file. Live: [link](https://www.denheldertexel.nl/live/live-archief-2017/)

Comment: @BartRos doing a console log on `color` before forEach will tell you what's inside the color array. So first make sure that you are adding the right values into color array. Add another console log inside the for loop as well. This problem needs some more debugging.

Comment: @Fawaz As I pointed out in my comment above, it gives me the same result inside the forEach as outside the forEach. See result in my Question.

Comment: @BartRos Sorry i wasn't able to convey properly, please check my answer below.

Comment: @BartRos, your problem is an asynchronous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try changing the line

```
var color = new Array();
```

to

```
var color = {};
```

What you may be looking for not an array but, the term in javascript, an `object`.

**EDIT**

After looking at the source and doing some debugging, the problem seems to be the asynchronous executions. You're `color` variable is being populated at a later time, which explains why `JSON.stringify` produces an empty object when printing which the `console.log` maintains the reference to the variable.

You'll want to ensure the `color` variable is populated first.

Some steps on how I debugged this, (using chrome):

- Open Chrome Dev Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I)
- Go to console
- Click on the line number that prints `undefined`
- You should be sent to the `sources` tab where you'll see your source code
- Here add a breakpoint by clicking on the line number (407, in this case)
- Refresh while on the dev tools window, (Ctrl+R)
- The javascript execution should stop at the debugger
- In this state mouse over variables on the source codes to see their values at that point in time
- You'll find that `color` is indeed an empty object
- So trace back to how `color` is being populated
- Find it nested under this code `d3.json(`
- That's when you know you got an asynchronous problem

Comment: var color = {}; only changes the color[] to color{}

Comment: Precisely, and then it works. You get an object with keys you can address. Arrays don't have keys, they're just a list.

Comment: Nope, `color[colour]` returns `undefined`

Comment: Oh god, after your edit, I realised that a whole part of my code was outside the async. request. Thank you a thousand times!

Answer (score 0):

This code here

```
for (var i = 0; i < datafeatures.length - 1; i++) {
    color[datafeatures[i].properties.userid] = datafeatures[i].properties.linecolor;
}
```

Should look more like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < datafeatures.length - 1; i++) {
    color.push({[datafeatures[i].properties.userid]: datafeatures[i].properties.linecolor})
}
```

It will give you the array you're looking for, I think.

Comment: Nope, you're constructing an array of objects : `[{26: "#9d36ee"} , {45: "#b1c743"}]`

Comment: Based on the fact that he started off by constructing a `new Array()` - I thought he might want an array of objects.

Comment: But then how do you get the coulour 63? This solution is more complex than it should be. OP doesn't know what he wants. He made an array, but doesn't _want_ it, because the solution here is really to build an object `{ "26" : "#9d36ee",
 "63" : "#b1c743"}` then you easily get the coulour 63 : `colours["63"]`.

Comment: @JeremyThille is correct. But when changing `var color = []` to 'var color = {}', I'm getting exactly the same result in console.log (only the '[]' is replaced by '{}')

Comment: Can we see the `snapshot` array ?

Comment: @ChristopherMesser The snapshot array has nothing to do with it (I think), but here you go: `var snapshot = <?= json_encode($usersfinished); ?>;`, this generates: `var snapshot = [{"name":"Eric Nottelman","title":"Den Helder - Texel 2017","wp_user":"64","fid":"64-Android119:00","timestamp":"1502560860000","distance_to_finish":"3,43 km"},...`.